# Javascript Map has duplicate keys

Tags: javascript

The Map object `set` method is meant to add a new key/pair, or update an existing key/pair. [See docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set).

I've been struggling to figure out how it is that my Map has ended up with duplicate keys when I attempt to populate it with database results:

```
let users = new Map();

function loadUserByName(name) {
    db.loadUser({ name }, (err, user) => {
        users.set(user.id, user);          
    });
}

loadUser('george');
users.forEach( (item) => { console.log(item.key); } );
// Output:
// 57bbfcb47ff30b00db69ae87

loadUser('george');
users.forEach( (item) => { console.log(item.key); } );
// Output:
// 57bbfcb47ff30b00db69ae87
// 57bbfcb47ff30b00db69ae87
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Map can have an object as the key. And just because two objects output as the same string, does not mean they are the same object. The above code can be fixed by casting `user.id` as a string i.e.:

```
function loadUserByName(name) {
    db.loadUser({ name }, (err, user) => {
        users.set(String(user.id), user);          
    });
}
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map  -  Key equality in Maps is based on the "same-value" algorithm: Keys are considered equal according to the semantics of the === operator.

Comment: At some point since the above comment, key equality in Maps was changed to use the "same-value-zero" algorithm. It is similar to same-value equality, but +0 and -0 are considered equal. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality